# Error with Protobuf while compiling Tensorflow

Tags: c++, makefile, tensorflow

I am currently trying use Tensorflow's shared libraries in a non-bazel project.

So I built the .so file using:

> bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so

Then I loaded the dependencies as described [here.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile)

I added the following flags to my Makefile:

> CFLAGS += -I/home/alpy/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles
>       CFLAGS += -I/home/alpy/tensorflow/
>       CFLAGS += -I/home/alpy/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/eigen-latest/
>
> LDFLAGS += -L../resources/
>
> LDFLAGS += -ltensorflow.so

When I do this, I get this rather strange error:

```
In file included from /home/alpy/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/public/session.h:22:0,
                 from ../src/conversion.h:14,
                 from ../src/conversion.cpp:1:
/home/alpy/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.pb.h:143:3: error: ‘PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED_ATTR’ does not name a type
   PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED_ATTR void clear_version();
   ^
/home/alpy/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.pb.h:144:3: error: ‘PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED_ATTR’ does not name a type
   PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED_ATTR static const int kVersionFieldNumber = 3;
   ^
/home/alpy/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.pb.h:145:3: error: ‘PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED_ATTR’ does not name a type
   PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED_ATTR ::google::protobuf::int32 version() const;
   ^
/home/alpy/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.pb.h:146:3: error: ‘PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED_ATTR’ does not name a type
   PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED_ATTR void set_version(::google::protobuf::int32 value);
   ^
/home/alpy/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.pb.h:273:37: error: no ‘void tensorflow::GraphDef::clear_version()’ member function declared in class ‘tensorflow::GraphDef’
 inline void GraphDef::clear_version() {
                                     ^
/home/alpy/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.pb.h:276:54: error: no ‘google::protobuf::int32 tensorflow::GraphDef::version() const’ member function declared in class ‘tensorflow::GraphDef’
 inline ::google::protobuf::int32 GraphDef::version() const {
                                                      ^
/home/alpy/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.pb.h:280:66: error: no ‘void tensorflow::GraphDef::set_version(google::protobuf::int32)’ member function declared in class ‘tensorflow::GraphDef’
 inline void GraphDef::set_version(::google::protobuf::int32 value) {
```

BTW, I loaded protobuf as it was described on the page I linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is resolved as described here: [Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!msg/discuss/CtrurAAnglI/Mu9JHr6kAQAJ)

Just add a new CFLAG:

```
-DPROTOBUF_DEPRECATED_ATTR=""
```